# Как удалить пересылаемое сообщение с помощью telebot?

Tags: telebot, python-telegram-bot, delete

В чате есть 1 пользователь, с помощью бота на telebot, ему запрещено отправлять ссылки на рекламу, новости, и так далее. Но есть нюанс. Когда он пересылает сообщение с другого канала, и там нет ссылки,то бот не удаляет его. Как сделать чтобы бот удалял пересылаемое сообщение?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы бот удалял пересылаемые сообщения, необходимо настроить обработку таких сообщений с помощью функции `forwarded_message_handler` в telebot.

Создайте функцию, которая будет обрабатывать пересылаемые сообщения:

```
def delete_forwarded_messages(message):
    if message.forward_from_chat:
        bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
```

Потом просто добавьте эту функцию в обработчик пересылаемых сообщений:

```
bot.forwarded_message_handler(func=delete_forwarded_messages)
```